# Delete a row when a cell is empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to delete a row when a cell is empty from the 'calories.xlsx' spreadsheet and send all data, except empty rows, to the 'destination.xlsx' spreadsheet. The code below is how far I got. But still, it does not delete rows that have an empty value based on the calories column.

This is the data set:

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX4V7.png)

How can I develop my code to solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd

FileName = 'calories.xlsx'
SheetName = pd.read_excel(FileName, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

df = SheetName

print(df)

ListCalories = ['Calories']

print(ListCalories)

for Cell in ListCalories:
    if Cell == 'NaN':
        df.drop[Cell]

print(df)

df.to_excel('destination.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

Create dummy data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'calories':[2306,3256,1235,np.nan,3654,3256],
    'Person':['person1','person2','person3','person4','person5','person6',]
    })
```

Print data frame

```
    calories    Person
0   2306.0  person1
1   3256.0  person2
2   1235.0  person3
3           person4
4   3654.0  person5
5   3256.0  person6
```

remove row, if calories value is missing

```
new_df=df.dropna(how='any',subset=['calories'])
```

Result

```
    calories    Person
0   2306.0     person1
1   3256.0     person2
2   1235.0     person3
4   3654.0     person5
5   3256.0     person6
```

save as excel

```
new_df.to_excel('destination.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

your `ListCalories` contains only one element which is `Calories`, I'll assume this was a typo.
what you are trying to probably do is

```
import pandas as pd

FileName = 'calories.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(FileName, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

print(df)

# you don't need this, but I kept it for you
ListCalories = df['Calories']
print(ListCalories)

clean_df = df[df['Calories'].notna()] # this will only select the rows that doesn't have na value in the Calories column

print(clean_df)

clean_df.to_excel('destination.xlsx')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html